# Regex to match alphabets only do not work with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am currently using this Regex (/^[A-z]+$/) to only allow users to enter alphabets only. But one problem I am facing is that it does not allow spaces between characters. Why is that and how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `[A-z]` you sure you understand what that allows?

Comment: Try `/^[a-z ]$/i`. Notice there is a space after `z`. Also notice `/i`. This makes check case insensitive. You can use regex101.com to test/ understand regex. [current regex](https://regex101.com/r/z7HyFL/1) vs [suggested regex](https://regex101.com/r/z7HyFL/2)

Comment: `\s` allows more than just space :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But one problem I am facing is that it does not allow spaces between
>   characters. Why is that and how to solve this problem?

You regex has `^` and `$` marking the start and end of your input, which means entire input must match `[A-z]+`.

You need to accommodate space as well, so try

```
/^[A-Z]+(([A-Z\s]*[A-Z])*)$/i
```

Explanation

- `[A-Z]+` ensures that it always starts with alphabets
- `(([A-Z\s]*[A-Z])*)` ensures that if there is a space between words it ends with alphabets as well

On the other hand, if you simply wanted to capture all the different words with alphabets in your sentence, simply

- Remove `^` and `$` from your regex,
- `[A-Z]` instead of `[A-z]`
- make it case insensitive

i.e.

```
/[A-Z]+/i
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you for the concise explanation. I have two questions for your regex.
1.  Why did you put the + sign after the [A-Z]?
2. I understand that the asterisk sign means that a character may be repeated multiple times, why did you put in the first asterisk between [A-Z\s] and [A-Z] instead of using it outside the bracket like the second asterisk.

Comment: So that your sentence always ends with an alphabet rather than space.